# The sum of the residues of a meromorphic differential form on a compact Riemann surface is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry

How can one see that the sum of the residues of a meromorphic function on a Riemann surface $
\Sigma_g$ of positive genus is always zero? This is not true for the Riemann sphere $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

Comment: How do you know that «this is not true» for the sphere?

Comment: (By the way, functions on Riemann surfaces do not have residues: meromorphic differential forms do...)

Comment: $1/z$ has non-zero residue $1$ on $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

Comment: Hi Mariano. I don't understand your second comment. Any meromorphic function has the Laurent expansion at each point and the residue is defined by the coeff of $1/z$, where $z$ is a local coordinate.

Comment: If you are going to sum the residues of $1/z$ over $P^1$, you need to include the residue at infinity, too.

Comment: The problem with defining the residue of a function on a surface is that that coefficient you refer to is not independent of the parametrization. (A better way of defining the residue of a function on the plane is as an integral along a curve cicing the point; now remember that the things you can integrate on a Riemann surface are the 1-forms, not the functions)

Comment: I see. Then my definition is wrong and they should be meromorphic differential forms.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : I seem to recall that someone once posted an answer that said differential forms rather than functions are the things that have residues, and this was in response to a question asking someone to resolve a paradox.  Might that have been you?  If so, do you have a link to that answer? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, not really, but for something to have a residue you need to be able to integrate it along curves, and you cannot integrate functions on Riemann surfaces but $1$-forms: these are precisely the things that can be integrated along curves.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : The instance I was thinking of involved only a curve in $\mathbb C$. $\qquad$

Comment: It doesn't matter. What you integrate along curves is always 1-forms. In the case of open sets in the plane, when you "integrate a function f" what you are *really* doing is integrating the 1-form fdz for the canonical coordinate chart.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : And what I wondering is: How did the knowledge that what one integrates is $1$-forms resolve a paradox.  I remember that it happened and now I'm realizing I don't remember the specifics. $\qquad$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming that you meant residues of meromorphic differential forms; Mariano explained in a comment why talking about residues of a function on a Riemann surface is a bad idea.

Take for example $\omega=\mathrm dz/z$ on the Riemann sphere $\mathbf P^1$. What this means, by the way, is that I define $\omega$ in local coordinates on the chart $\mathbf P^1-\{\infty\}$ by $\omega=\mathrm dz/z$. Because of the isolated zeroes theorem, there is at most one form on $\mathbf P^1$ that coincides with $\mathrm dz/z$ on $\mathbf P^1-\{\infty\}$. To see that there is indeed such a form, you have to check that when you make a change of coordinates in $\mathrm dz/z$ to work in a chart around $\infty$, what you get is meromorphic. I choose the chart $\mathbf P^1-\{0\}$ with coordinate $w=1/z$; in that chart, the form is written $\omega=-\mathrm dw/w$ because $\mathrm dz=-\mathrm dw/w^2$. As you can see, $\mathrm{Res}_0(\omega)=1$ and $\mathrm{Res}_\infty(\omega)=-1$, so their sum is $0$.

Now, in general, take a compact Riemann surface $X$ and a meromorphic 1-form $\omega$ on $X$ with poles $p_1,\ldots,p_n$. Around each $p_i$, consider a small simple loop $\gamma_i$, and denote by $U_i$ the interior of the loop. Let $X'$ be the complement of $\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ in $X$. The sum of the residues is
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Res}_{p_i}(\omega)
&= \frac1{2i\pi}\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\gamma_i}\omega\\
&= \frac1{2i\pi}\int_\gamma\omega
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ is the chain $\gamma_1+\cdots+\gamma_n$. Notice that the boundary of $X'$ is precisely $-\gamma$, so by Stokes' theorem you get
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Res}_{p_i}(\omega)
= -\frac1{2i\pi}\iint_{X'}\mathrm d\omega.
$$
But $X'$ stays far away from the poles of $\omega$, so $\omega$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $X'$, hence $\mathrm d\omega=0$ on $X'$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the claim is true for $meromorphic$ 1-$form$ on any Riemann surface.

Comment: On any *compact* Riemann surface, yes.

Comment: Very well put answer!

Comment: Let me get this right (I don't know complex geometry): do we have $d=\partial+\overline{\partial}$ and then, on $X'$, it's $\overline{\partial}\omega=0$ since $\omega$ is holomorphic there and $\partial\omega=0$ since there aren't non-zero $(2,0)$-forms on a Riemann surface?