# $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\operatorname{Res}(f,z_{i}) + \operatorname{Res}(f,\infty) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, reference-request, residue-calculus

Let $f \in H(\mathbb{C}- \{ z_{1}, \dots, z_{n} \})$.

I need a proof of the fact that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\operatorname{Res}(f,z_{i}) + \operatorname{Res}(f,\infty) = 0.$$

Where can I find it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the relation between residues and integrals of $f$ (i.e., the residue theorem), the equality follows from the fact that for $R>\max |z_k|$ we can compute $\int_{|z|=R}f(z)\,dz$ in two ways: via the sum of residues over interior region:
$$\int_{|z|=R}f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{Res}(f,z_k)$$
and via the sum of residues over exterior region: 
$$\int_{|z|=R}f(z)\,dz = - 2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f,\infty)$$

See also [The sum of the residues of a meromorphic differential form on a compact Riemann surface is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/441813/)

Randomly picked references: [Inside-Outside theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inside-OutsideTheorem.html) on Wolfram Mathworld, Theorem 6 on page 5 of *The Cauchy Method of Residues: Theory and Applications, Volume 2* by D. S. Mitrinovic, Jovan D. Kečkić.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know a book I can use ?

Comment: @WLOG Any book with the work "residue" in it. I can't imagine a book that introduces residues and does not relate them to integrals.

Comment: In the books I know there isn't the demonstration of this specific formula

Comment: @WLOG I would not expect a demonstration of the fact that $b=-a$ implies $a+b=0$.