# Doubt in Residue Theorem and Meromorphic function on Sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, meromorphic-functions

I have come across the following two statements.

> By Riemann Roch theorem on $\mathbb CP^1$ due to g=0, we have dim $H^0(P)=2$ where P is seen as the divisor $1.P$, but $H^0(0)=1$, here 0 is the trivial zero divisor.

This means that there is a function with exactly one pole at P and no other poles.

> Residue Theorem : Sum of residues = 0

So it seems like there can't be a function with exactly one pole at exactly one point.

What am I misunderstanding? Kindly clear my doubt.

Comment: The version of the Residue Theorem I know states that the sum of the residues of a *meromorphic differential* (not a meromorphic function) is zero. And isn't the function with a simple pole at $P$ and no other poles just $1/(z - P)$ if $P \in \mathbb{C}$, and $z$ if $P = \infty$?

Comment: A related post (maybe even a duplicate): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441813/the-sum-of-the-residues-of-a-meromorphic-differential-form-on-a-compact-riemann

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The sum of the residues of a meromorphic differential form on a compact Riemann surface is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441813/the-sum-of-the-residues-of-a-meromorphic-differential-form-on-a-compact-riemann)